# Animal species anatomy

Tags: zoology, human-anatomy, anatomy, kidney, lungs

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal

Do all animal species have two lungs and two kidneys similar to human beings?

Comment: You made this completely unreadable with your edits, which seem to be completely unexplained links. The question itself is very underresearched, but adding random links does not help that. You are fortunate that someone gave you an answer anyways.

Comment: I just saw your edit, it completely changes your question and makes it much more vague and hard to give a specific answer to. Even just "do you feel" makes the question opinion-based and thus inappropriate for the site. Do you want information, or a debate? For a debate, try reddit. For information, put more thought into what info you really want and which question could best elicit it (for example "do all animals have 2 lungs and 2 kidneys" was clearly not a good question for the info you really wanted). As @BryanKrause said, looking for the answer yourself could also help focus the question.

Comment: The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Unresearched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please see our [homework policy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) for more information. In this case, merely looking at the Wiki articles for lung and kidney would give you the answer.

Answer (score 2):

No.
[Lungs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lung) are a feature of tetrapods (land vertebrates) and some lungfish. Many fish have swim bladders, which are thought to be [homologous to lungs](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Homology-of-lungs-and-gas-bladders%3A-Insights-from-Longo-Riccio/f3f4f107d25919ab2bf830658e5c8d995af825ad) (they evolved from the same ancestral structure) but are not lungs, and I don't think they come in pairs anyway. Some other air-breathing organisms evolved air-breathing structures that also get called "lungs" but they are not related to human lungs, like spider ["book lungs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_lung)", and those don't necessarily come in pairs either (for example, spiders can have apparently one to four such lungs).

[Kidneys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidney) are an organ specific to vertebrates.

It's worth noting that even the concept of having "two X" is specific to bilaterians, which is animals that show left-right symmetry. That includes all your vertebrates and insects and worms and squids and such, but it does not include animals like jellyfish, sponges or corals. You also have animals that are in the bilaterian family, and do have left-right symmetry in some life stages, but don't in others, like starfish and sea urchins.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please give the references of the medical books, encyclopaedia, medical dictionaries, medical journals, Wikipedia etc where this information is cited?

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar You are asking for far too much effort for the amount of effort you have put in for your own question. What is the motivation here? The answerer here has provided plenty of reasonable evidence against the idea that every animal has 2 lungs and 2 kidneys. We don't need medical texts about arthropods and fish because there is very little medical interest in those animals.

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar dude I did, look at the links.

Comment: This is an excellent answer to a really lousy question. However, in the future, I would suggest not answering very low quality, unresearched questions like these. From [How do I write a good answer?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [help], *`Answer well-asked questions. Not all questions can or should be answered here.`*